# Why C# inline if result is different than if?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code :

```
object w = 44;
var k1 = (w is double
       ? ((Convert.ToSingle(w)))
       : ((unchecked((uint)Convert.ToInt64(w)))));
if (w is double)
{
    w = 22;
}
```

The result is that `k1` = 44.0 and `w` == 44;

I wonder why the results is different!

Let's assume `w` is double, in this case `k1` should be 44.0 and `w` should be 22.

Now let's assume `w` is not double, in this case `k1` should be 44 and `w` should be 44.

What is the problem !?

Comment: which environment you are using?

Comment: I *think* your problem is that you can't use `? :` syntax to return two different types. `k1` is inferred to be a single because the first case of your `if` returns a single and the `uint` returned from the second part is silently converted.

Comment: Also, the dead give away is if you test the type of `k1`, even just hovering over it in Visual Studio will tell you it's a `float`.

Comment: Another way to see what's happening, try `var foo = true ? "hi" : 1;` Note this will give you a compiler error because it can't convert 1 to a string implicitly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of the conditional expression used to initialize `k1` is the same no matter what type `w` turns out to be.  The compiler has to determine the conditional expression type at compile time based on the types of the 2 possible values.

```
cond ? float: uint
```

These types are not the same but `uint` can implicitly convert to `float` hence the compiler chooses that as the return type

Answer (score 2):

`w` is an int (44).
The type of your ternary expression is a float, therefore `k1` is float.

Therefore the 'false' branch of your ternary is executed and `k1` is:

```
k1 = (float)((unchecked((uint)Convert.ToInt64(w)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe:

```
object w = 44;
object k1 = (w is double ? (object)((Convert.ToSingle(w))) : (object)((unchecked((uint)Convert.ToInt64(w)))));
if (w is double)
{
    w = 22;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", w.GetType(), k1.GetType());

Console.ReadLine();
```

Magic, it now tells you it's an uint :-)

The problem is the implicit conversion from uint to float, which is because of the ternary condition.